# How to know which distribution/development provisioning profile my app is using

Tags: ios, ios5, code-signing, provisioning-profile

Currently in development and testing phase, in order to distribute my app amoung test team I created multiple provisioning profiles and somehow managed to run my app on different devices for testing, now I want to know which provisioning profile my app is actually using? and from which certificate my app is signed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the name of the app in the tree on the left.  Then:  Build Settings/Code Signing Identity